# ASP.NET Setting width of DataBound column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which uses BoundField for columns. I am trying to set a maxwidth for my `UserInfo` column.

I have tried many many ways but non of them work. Below is the code for my *GridView* :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
ondatabound="gv_DataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserId" 
                DataField="UserId" 
                SortExpression="UserId"></asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Username" 
                DataField="Username" 
                SortExpression="Username"></asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserInfo" 
                DataField="UserInfo" 
                SortExpression="UserInfo"></asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Looking for suggestions on how I can set the width of a specific column, which is my `UserInfo` column.

Comment: in css property of that just give "width:auto"
It will expand the column automatically

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did a small demo for you. Demonstrating how to display long text.

In this example there is a column Name which may contain very long text. The **boundField** will display all content in a table cell and therefore the **cell will expand as needed** (because of the content)

The **TemplateField** will also be rendered as a cell BUT it contains a **div** which **limits** the **width** of any contet to eg 40px. So this column will have some kind of max-width!

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPersons" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name (long)" DataField="Name">
                <ItemStyle Width="40px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name (short)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="width: 40px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                        <%# Eval("Name") %>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Here is my demo codeBehind

```
 public partial class gridViewLongText : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         #region init and bind data
         List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
         list.Add(new Person(1, "Sam"));
         list.Add(new Person(2, "Max"));
         list.Add(new Person(3, "Dave"));
         list.Add(new Person(4, "TabularasaVeryLongName"));
         gvPersons.DataSource = list;
         gvPersons.DataBind();
         #endregion
     }
 }

 public class Person
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public Person(int _ID, string _Name)
     {
         ID = _ID;
         Name = _Name;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

add HeaderStyle in your bound field:

```
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserId"
                DataField="UserId" 
                SortExpression="UserId">

                <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />

</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. My column still extends vertically due to the long input

Comment: Works for me, thanks.  Nice clean, simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Width can be set to specific column as below:
By percentages:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserInfo"  DataField="UserInfo"  
SortExpression="UserInfo" ItemStyle-Width="100%"></asp:BoundField>
```

OR

By pixel:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserInfo"  DataField="UserInfo"  
SortExpression="UserInfo" ItemStyle-Width="500px"></asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: where does the percentage get the value from? percentage of value from?

Comment: Do you need to set the width dynamically? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to work for all situations while working with width.

```
`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATE">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date") %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
ondatabound="gv_DataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" width="600px">

<Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserId" 
                DataField="UserId" 
                SortExpression="UserId" ItemStyle-Width="400px"></asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: It does not work for me too. I have the AutoGenerateColumns to false if that matters.

Answer (score -1):

hey recently i figured it out how to set width if your gridview databound with sql dataset.first set these control `RowStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"` and then you can set the column width as much as you like. ex : `ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px"`