# GridView BoundField break long string

Tags: asp.net, gridview

One of BoundField in my GridView has very long string **without spaces** and it resize GridView. How to break long strings in GridView columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution which works in my situation

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="350px" HeaderText="Source">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="width: 350px;word-wrap:break-word; ">
                <%# Eval("Source")%>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: don't you have the possibility to restrict text size with "text(...)" and display all text in a tooltip?

Comment: Been looking everywere for this.

Answer (score 5):

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="DataField" HeaderText="HeaderText"  ItemStyle-  CssClass="breakword" />
 .breakword
 {
 word-wrap:break-word;
 word-break:break-all;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this question [Setting width of bound column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266580/asp-net-setting-width-of-databound-column-in-gridview)

Anyway a quick solution for your problem will make use of a **template field** and using **word-wrap attribute**.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name (short)">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="width: 40px; word-wrap: break-word;">
               <%# Eval("Name") %>
           </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

hth

Comment: The biggest problem of your solution is that Text is hidden, I would like to break it to next line and show it fully to user.

Comment: just rewrote answer- use word-wrap: break-word