# GridView BoundField long string in Edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

One of BoundField in my GridView has a very long string without space. I want to dispaly it correctly. According to the similar [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587538/gridview-boundfield-break-long-string)
I used the code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ICD9" ItemStyle-Width="75px" SortExpression="ICD9" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
                                <%# Eval("ICD9")%>
                                </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Although it works, but when I switch it the Edit mode. The column can not be editted.The textbox doesn't show up.

Thanks.
[image]

Please look at the second column, it may has a long string.(Right now it is "None").
It can not be editted.

Comment: You've showed the `ItemTemplate` but your issue is in the [EditItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx), isn't it?

Comment: But why other columns can be editted? They don't have EditTemplate. I use stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `<TemplateField>`, you also need an `<EditItemTemplate>`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ICD9" ItemStyle-Width="75px" SortExpression="ICD9" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <%# Eval("ICD9")%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 75px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Bind("ICD9") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This way, when your `GridView` goes into edit mode, it knows what to render for that field.

Without being able to see your other fields, it's possible they are working because they are simply `<BoundField>`s, which would have this behavior by default (when in the TemplateField, you have to explicitly define the edit and non-edit modes).

You can take a look at this (sort of old) tutorial for more information on TemplateFields: [Using TemplateFields in the GridView control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Comment: @Love Hmmm, you might have to set `TextMode="MultiLine"` on that TextBox to get it to wrap.  You'd then somehow have to set the height dynamically, but hopefully that gets you started.  Let me know if that works for you.